# Spring Boot: how to use multiple yml files

Tags: java, spring, yaml, spring-boot

In Spring Boot, I know that I can replace application.properties with application.yml and use the YAML format.
However, my application.yml is getting crowded so I need to split it up a bit. How can I do that? I would like to do something like this:

```
...
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableScheduling
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.yml", "classpath:scheduling.yml"})
public class ApplicationConfig {
...
```

Comment: Maybe this approach may work:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28303758/how-to-use-yamlpropertiesfactorybean-to-load-yaml-files-using-spring-framework-4

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`@PropertySource` does not support YAML (probably it will in Spring 4.1). You can set `spring.config.location` or `spring.config.name` to a comma-separated list (e.g. as System property or command line argument).

Personally I like all my YAML in the same place (the structure really helps to break it up visually, and you can use documents inside the file to split it up more). That's just taste I guess.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep it in one file for now then. It would be nicer to split it up though, but I will wait for Spring 4.1.

Comment: For integration testing, if you want to having application.yml file in test/resources and if you want to override only few attributes other than /java/resources how can you do that

Comment: Use `@ActiveProfiles` and only put the overrides in the profile you use for testing. Or use `@IntegrationTest`. Or `ReflectionTestUtils`.

Comment: It's nice to put everything in the same place until it becomes too large to maintain, in which case breaking things up like the questioner asks is ideal.

Comment: The feature request to add support to YAML files to `@PropertySource` was never implemented, and has been closed: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18486. The comments by the Spring developers indicate pushback on adding it, since users were wanting to use it in a Spring Boot context where it was not a proper fix.

Answer (score 57):

1. remove `@PropertySource` annotation, you not need it
2. rename your `scheduling.yml` into `src/main/resources/application-scheduling.yml`
3. add in `src/main/resources/application.yml` file next line:

   `spring.profiles.include: 'scheduling'`

Comment: I think the OP wants to have properties grouped by different yaml files. Does your solution solve that issue?

Answer (score 20):

if I have a lot of configurations and/or environments, usually I do so:

```
$ cat src/main/resources/application.yml:
spring:
  profiles:
    include: >
      profile1,
      profile2,
      ...
      profileN

$ ls -lah src/main/resources/config:
drwxr-xr-x  4 mak  staff   136B Apr 16 23:58 .
drwxr-xr-x  6 mak  staff   204B Apr 17 01:54 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 mak  staff    60B Apr 16 23:58 application-profile1.yml
-rw-r--r--  1 mak  staff    62B Apr 16 23:16 application-profile2.yml
...
-rw-r--r--  1 mak  staff    50B Apr 16 23:16 application-profileN.yml
```

Answer (score 11):

Suppose your application need 4 .yml files.

```
application.yml
application-dev.yml
application-uat.yml
application-prod.yml
```

and you have to set different setting for each file.

You just need to set your setting on appropriate environment such as dev, uat ot prod level and the have to add just one property in `application.yml` file.

```
  spring:  
    profiles:
       active: dev
    application: /* optional */
       name: Application Name
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use active profile concept in your main yaml file. For example:

```
spring.profiles.active: test
```

that means you should have `application-test.yml` file in your resource directory. Consider that active profiles will override properties with the same names in your main yaml file.

For more information visit:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

Answer (score 3):

All answers are fiddling with profiles.

However as stated here:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-load-multiple-yaml-configuration-files

> 'While this method works,  a drawback is that it uses the Spring
> profiles functionality in a way that is most likely not intended by
> the implementation.'

Probably, the cleaner way would be

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource(value = "classpath:application-teachers.yml", factory = MultipleYamlPropertySourceFactory.class),
public class MultipleYamlConfiguration {

    List<String> teachers;    

}
```

... see the link for full example