# yaml configuration in spring mvc (But not using spring-boot)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-java-config

Is there a way to enable yaml configuration (instead of properties file) in normal spring web mvc application without using spring boot and have the @Value annotation supported.

I searched a lot, everywhere it uses spring boot. I am not intrested to use spring boot, as its very heavy and have many dependancies configured for auto setup.

Any help would be appreciated......

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by YAML configuration?  Do you mean reading attributes from a YAML file into a bean with the `@Value` annotation?

Comment: Yes....absolutly, instead of using properties file, I would like to use yaml

Comment: Take a look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21272560/1458983

Comment: Its not a good solution, i am looking for exactly the same way we use properties files

Comment: Well, if you are not willing to use the Spring Boot util classes, I think that you are out of luck.

Comment: See also: [How to use YamlPropertiesFactoryBean to load YAML files using Spring Framework 4.1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28303758)

Comment: Thanks...I did it as specified in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28303758

Comment: just take a look at this answer here:[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271468/spring-propertysource-using-yaml/54247009#54247009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271468/spring-propertysource-using-yaml/54247009#54247009) .it`s easy to use.