# Spring application deployment failing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gitlab

I am trying to deploy a Kubernetes cluster of a spring application using argocd And I am getting errors in it. I am using an GitLab ci pipeline first to build its docker image and then using argocd for the continuous deployment. The error is:

```
Springapi error logs

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-05-25 16:24:33.389 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'consentDataController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'ipScoreService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'IPScoreService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'application-flags.load-ip-db-in-memory' in value "${application-flags.load-ip-db-in-memory}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4]
    at com.dronapay.api.ApiApplication.main(ApiApplication.java:13) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[api.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[api.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[api.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[api.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'IPScoreService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'application-flags.load-ip-db-in-memory' in value "${application-flags.load-ip-db-in-memory}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:405) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'application-flags.load-ip-db-in-memory' in value "${application-flags.load-ip-db-in-memory}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:180) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:239) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:936) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
```

I am not getting anything to solve this issue if anyone has any idea about it then please reply.

Here is my config file:

This is my application.yml file where everything is configured.

```
 config:
   activate:
     on-profile: prod
 datasource:
   URL: <DB_HOST>
   username: <DBUSER>
   password: <DBPWD>
   hikari:
     minimimIdle: 2
     maximumPoolSize: 10
     idleTimeout: 300000
     maxLifetime: 2000000
     connectionTimeout: 30000
 redis:
   host: <Redis_Host>
   port: 6379
   database: 0
   password: <pass>
   timeout: 60000
 jpa:
   open-in-view: true
   show-sql: false
   generate-ddl: false
   database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
   hibernate:
     naming:
       implicit-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl
       physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
     dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
     ddl-auto: none
 servlet:
   multipart:
     max-file-size: 3MB
server:
 port: 8080
 error:
   include-message: always
kafka:
 #bootstrap-servers: localhost:19092
 bootstrap-servers: <kafka_bootstrap_host>:9092
 consumer:
   group-id: "api"
ingress-topic: ingress
egress-topic: scored
lists-topic: listed
file-upload-path: /mnt/d/docker_data/uploaded
auth:
 apikey: false
 apikeyfile: apikey.txt
application-flags:
 kafka: false
 double-debit: false
 load-ip-db-in-memory: false
logging:
 config: /mnt/d/docker_data/logback.xml
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide the `application-flags.load-ip-db-in-memory`.

Comment: Plus, If you use `@Value` annotation to inject it from `properties` files, you can use default values in order to prevent this exception.
`@Value("${application-flags.load-ip-db-in-memory:<your-default-value-here>}")`

Comment: I added my config file in question. please check it and tell if anything wrong in it.

Answer (score 0):

This problem may occur from different reasons.

1. If you provide the variables from environment variable `${application-flags.load-ip-db-in-memory}`, your current terminal that you execute `java -jar <application>.jar` has the property. You can check it out by writing `printenv` on shell screen.
2. If you execute the application on IDE, you need to provide it on configuration section of the IDE. For example on IntellijA[image]

3. As mentioned in comments you can set defaults for that exception.

Comment: I added my config file in question. please check it and tell if anything wrong in it.

Answer (score 0):

the @Value("${application-flags.load-ip-db-in-memory}")

is null
check if you are wrong

or you can use
@Value("${application-flags.load-ip-db-in-memory : here default value if its not in the app.prop }")
private String someDefault;

Comment: I added my config file in question. please check it and tell if anything wrong in it.

Comment: check this link will help you [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/63463804/17569519)