# Spring Boot yaml nested property map to Configuration class HashMap

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

I have a configuration class named `CommonConfig` that has been working fine so far…

```
@Data
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = “my")
public class CommonConfig {
  private String foo;
  private String bar;
  private SubA subA;

  @Data 
  public static class SubA {
    private String baz;
    private SubB subB;

    @Data 
    public static class SubB {
      private String qux;
    }
  }
}
```

And the `Yaml property` file to go with that:

```
my.foo: a
my.bar: b
my.sub-a.baz: c
my.sub-a.sub-b.qux: d
```

My problem started when I wanted to get a `map` into SubB:

```
my:
  foo: a
  bar: b
  sub-a:
    baz: c
    sub-b:
      qux: d
      map:
        number-one: 1
        number-two: 2
        number-three: 3
```

I tried adding a simple map declaration inside my SubB class:

```
...
@Data 
public static class SubB {
  private String qux;
  private Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
}
```

When I run this though, all the other properties are in the config, but the map is empty.
I also tried not initializing the map, but it stays null.

My `@SpringBootApplication` class has previously been working fine with just that one annotation on it.  Based on some other StackOverflow questions, I tried adding `@EnableConfigurationProperties`, but it made no difference.

Comment: Works for me. If you post a link to a complete project we might be able to see what you did that you aren't telling us.

Comment: Thank you very much for checking!  I made the sample as described and it worked for me as well so I started porting over my actual app to see what was different.  It all boiled down to not reading a property file because the application name didn't match.  Chalk another one up to PEBKAC or ID-10-T error. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example does indeed work fine.  My particular problem was a config file that wasn't being read.

Answer (score 1):

1. In case of YAML files, `application.yml`gets loaded automatically. If the file name is something else, Spring won't auto-load that.
2. `@PropertySource` as of SprintBoot 2.1 doesn't work for YAML
3. in case the YAML file needs a different name, we need to set  `spring.config.name` and  `spring.config.location`

    https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-yaml
4. Following link also points to a good answer:

    [Reading a map from yaml in Java getting null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34697611/reading-a-map-from-yaml-in-java-getting-null)