# Read string array from named yaml properties list as a constant?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml, spring-kafka

Is it possible with Spring Java to read a string-array from a map of named values from a YAML file as a constant (specifically for use with the `@KafkaListener` annotation from Spring-Kafka)?

```
   a:
     b:
       topics:
         foo: FooTopic
         bar: BarTopic
```

Would result in a constant =  ['FooTopic','BarTopic'].

I'm assuming it would be something similar to the expression that evaluates to a list as with some of the examples from [ [Reading a List from properties file and load with spring annotation @Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576156/reading-a-list-from-properties-file-and-load-with-spring-annotation-value) ]. I'm just unsure of what the syntax might be, as the only way I've seen is using multiple annotations to construct a POJO like [ [Reading a map from yaml in Java getting null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34697611/reading-a-map-from-yaml-in-java-getting-null) ] which doesn't work in the `@KafkaListener` annotation context.

Note: The topics need to be named as they are extracted individually in a different context.

Edit: spelling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not going to work that way without extracting `@ConfigurationProperties`.

This is what I have in a forehead:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = {"${kafka.topics.foo}", "${kafka.topics.bar}"})
```

But at the same time having this:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("kafka")
public class KafkaAppProperties {

    private Map<String, String> topics  = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<String, String> getTopics() {
        return this.topics;
    }

}
```

I can do:

```
 @KafkaListener(topics = "#{@'kafka-org.springframework.integration.samples.kafka.KafkaAppProperties'.topics.values()}")
```

Right, that bean name for the `KafkaAppProperties` looks awkward, but we can overcome it with the artificial bean:

```
@Autowired
private KafkaAppProperties properties;

@Bean
public Map<String, String> kafkaTopic() {
    return this.properties.getTopics();
}

...

@KafkaListener(topics = "#{@kafkaTopic.values()}")
public void handle(Object record) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I keep getting a 'NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` regardless of whether I explicitly create a bean in the configuration or whether I just use the 'awkward' method of having everything in the annotation. It was almost like the `@KafkaListener` was looking for the bean before it was created. Thoughts?

Comment: Yup; looks exactly like the POJO in your example, just with a different string to represent the YAML path.

Comment: OK. Do you have then `@EnableConfigurationProperties(KafkaAppProperties.class)` on one of  your `@Configuration`/`@SpringBootApplication` ?

Comment: I didn't originally (was trying just using the `@Bean` annotation), but I just tried adding that in below the `@Configuration` and it resulted in the same error.

Comment: Not sure what's going on in your application. Everything I have shared with you I checked on this sample application: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/kafka

Comment: Turned out to be a naming thing, and possibly an unneeded annotation that was messing with bean creation; it works now though. Thanks for the help!