# spring cloud config - how to read value as a Map from external yaml file

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

From config server, I want to inject the property in to my service as a Map.
I can do this with @ConfigurationProperties annotation; however using the @Value (along with @RefreshScope) it reads from the config server; however throws an exception:
Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.util.Map]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found

---

```
application.yml:(in config server)
user:
  test:
    key1:
      val1,val2
    key2:
      val1,val2
```

---

```
@Service
//@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="user")
@RefreshScope
public class Example {

    @Value("${user}")
    Map<String, List<String>> test;

}
```

Comment: You don't need `@RefreshScope` or `@Service` on `@ConfigurationProperties`. `@ConfigurationProperties` by default is in the refresh scope.

Comment: Thanks for responding. and also the problem that I had of the property not loading as a map from config server is fixed by removing the     @value annotation and providing the get/set for test variable. 
    `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="user")
        public class Example {

            Map<String, List<String>> test;
            public Map<String, List<String>> getTest() {
      return test;
     }

     public void setTest(Map<String, List<String>> tet) {
   this.test = test;
     }
    }`

Comment: Please check my comment about how to read YAML file in Spring and include it in JUnit and TestNG test here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37270778/3634283