# Is it possible to have a yml configuration file alongside the regular application.yml (Java Springboot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

I have an application with an application.yml, but I want another configuration file by the name foo.yml. I can't seem to get it to work. What's wrong with my code?

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test")
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:foo.yml")
public class All {
    String oof;
    // getters and setters and toString
}
```

My foo.yml

```
test:
    oof: "bloof"
```

My test, where oof outputs as null instead of bloof

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
class AllTest {

    @Autowired
    private All all;

    @Test
    public void test {
        System.out.println(all.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use profiles, name it application-foo.yml?

Comment: I just tried that and it still doesn't work, so I'm starting to think I messed something up in my test? Do you see any issues?

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37974776/spring-boot-load-multiple-yaml-files answers your question ?

Comment: @yAzou yes it does, thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot - Load multiple YAML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37974776/spring-boot-load-multiple-yaml-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `.yml` is not supported by `@PropertySource(value=..)`
From
[doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html):

> Both traditional and XML-based properties file formats are supported — for example, "classpath:/com/myco/app.properties" or "file:/path/to/file.xml".