# Spring boot jsp and application.yml

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I use an *application.yml* based spring-boot for a project. As example project I used https://github.com/ghillert/spring-boot-jsp-demo/blob/master/jsp-demo-tomcat/src/main/resources/application.properties works very good so far.

I was so brave to change the settings from *application.properties*

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

to

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

Unfortunaetly after changing the properties the example is not working anymore. Is it possible to configure the given properties in the way I do in application.yml? Or how do I configure the settings otherwise?

Comment: why cant you use .yml instead of .properties?

Comment: The project already has migrated to use yml files :-( And its working only for the jsp part not

Comment: @TechBreak isn't that exactly the thing OP is trying to do?

Comment: @eis i am confused from name of file. application.properties

Comment: @TechBreak -  in first post I had a spelling error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. With Spring-Boot 1.3 the property name changed from spring.view.prefix to spring.mvc.view.prefix. Make sure you are using the right name.
2. Also make sure that the dependency to org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper is not marked as *provided* when you are in Spring-Boot standalone mode. Otherwise the JspServlet will not be registered as a Servlet-Mapping in TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory as it's not in the classpath.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create `application.yml` file in your `src/main/resources` folder (you have got `application.properties` at the moment in your project, which needs to be deleted), it should be as shown below:

```
spring: 
       mvc:
           view:
                prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
                suffix: .jsp
```

**P.S.: Make sure that the indentation is exactly same, otherwise if you use tabs, you will get the exception like 'found character '\t(TAB)' that cannot start any token. (Do not use \t(TAB) for indentation)'**

Comment: The IDE should be able to set "tabs to spaces" for you so using the Tab key should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using springs capabilities here,

i.e. YamlPropertiesFactoryBean

The YamlPropertiesFactoryBean will load YAML as Properties.

Also check this link if that helps,

[How to use YamlPropertiesFactoryBean to load YAML files using Spring Framework 4.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28303758/how-to-use-yamlpropertiesfactorybean-to-load-yaml-files-using-spring-framework-4)

Comment: in the case of just Spring, yes. OP is however using Spring Boot, which [supports YAML out of the box](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).

Comment: @eis agree but in case resources are not picking then this could be handy by explicitly putting required file from classpath?