# Can we use application.yml file with a spring-core application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, application.properties

I have developed a spring core independent jar and using application.properties with it.

My question is can we use application.yml instead of application.properties with this jar?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use YamlPropertiesFactoryBean to load YAML files using Spring Framework 4.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28303758/how-to-use-yamlpropertiesfactorybean-to-load-yaml-files-using-spring-framework-4)

Comment: Thanks.. it worked

Answer (score 0):

yes you can, just replace this with yml file.Its just Application-properties file written in json like format