# Read secrets as files using spring.cloud.kubernetes.secrets.paths property

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-kubernetes

Is there an example of howto use `spring.cloud.kubernetes.secrets.paths=/mnt/secrets-store` property to read secrets as files (mounted as a volume)?

My Pod.yaml

```yaml
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-mounted-secrets
  namespace: default
  labels:
    aadpodidbinding: pod-mi
spec:
  containers:
    - name: nginx
      image: nginx
      volumeMounts:
        - name: foo
          mountPath: "/mnt/secrets-store"
          readOnly: true
  volumes:
    - name: foo
      csi:
        driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
        readOnly: true
        volumeAttributes:
          secretProviderClass: spc
```

When I run the Pod the secrets are mounted

```sh
kubectl -n default exec -it nginx-mounted-secrets -- bash
root@nginx-mounted-secrets:/# ls /mnt/secrets-store
service-one-secret
service-two-secret
```

I've tried the following but the fields do not get populated:

```java
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
@Data
public class ApplicationSecrets {

    private String serviceOneSecret;
    private String serviceTwoSecret;

}
```

I'm using

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-config</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In a general spring application `ConfigurationProperties` properties are build with prefixes in mind
for separation of concerns(i.e spring properties vs application properties..).

Following your yml structure, there are some different concerns of your properties: metadata, spec (split up into containers and volumes)

So for your implementation to work either:

1. Define `@ConfigurationProperties` with correct prefixes for each sub-tree and use them accordingly

2.[OR] Load the yml properties and look them up via @Value, using a custom propertyPlaceholder as in this answer: [How to use YamlPropertiesFactoryBean to load YAML files using Spring Framework 4.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28303758/how-to-use-yamlpropertiesfactorybean-to-load-yaml-files-using-spring-framework-4) and them autowire all properties in a map for example (this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691949/how-to-inject-a-map-using-the-value-spring-annotation) with the `@Value("#{${propertyname}}")  private Map<String,String> propertyname;`

Comment: what's the correct prefix for the path `ls /mnt/secrets-store` I've tried `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "secrets-store")`

Comment: for example `prefix=spec.containers` for reading everything in that subtree (i.e name, image, volumeMounts). Also you can have spec.volumes for reading everything bellow(i.e names, csi...)

Answer (score 0):

I think what might have been missing in your case is letting spring know where the secrets are mounted. I've done this via `bootstrap.yaml` file (mounted next to application jar).

```
spring:
  cloud:
    kubernetes:
      secrets:
        # this would be "/mnt/secrets-store" in your case
        paths: /etc/secrets
        enabled: true
      config:
        name: "config-map-name"
        enabled: true
...
```

Notes:

1. `bootstrap.yaml` mounted next to the jar completely overwrites the content of a `bootstrap.yaml` bundled inside the app (there is no cascading like in case of `application.yaml`.
2. I'm running `2.0.1`

I can post more configuration bits if you need it.

Comment: could you please share little more ,basically how you accessing that secrets using spring boot ?

Comment: I have limited time today so I would direct you towards the [official docs](https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/config-file-processing-in-spring-boot-2-4) for now (search for `Volume Mounted Configuration Trees`). 

I believe my answer is now a little outdated as well.

I would need some time to put together a minimal example.

Comment: Based on the doc, I think in this case you prob want path `/mnt` and `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "secrets-store")`, instead of path being `/mnt/secrets-store`. I hope this might help somebody coming up.