# Is there any way to divide application properties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a very large application.yml file. Also, there are business and tech properties are close together.

I want to split this properties to different files, such as: "application.yml", "domain.yml", "restrictions.yml" and so on.

How can I tell spring to use an exact properties file in my Config.java bean?
I'm telling exactly about ".yml" extension, cause ".properties" works fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot and multiple external configuration files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855795/spring-boot-and-multiple-external-configuration-files)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23134869/spring-boot-how-to-use-multiple-yml-files

Comment: You can put all the yaml files in a `config` subdirectory, all of them will be loaded.