# How to make spring.profile.include to include YAML files from subfolder?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I currently have 4 YAML files

```
application.yaml
application-local.yaml
application-test.yaml
application-dev.yaml
```

I assume that `application.yaml` is acting as `default`.

In the other 3 files contains

```
spring:
  profiles:
    include: default
```

My problem is that my `application.yaml` is very large 
and it contains properties that are hierarchical.

For example,

```
connection:
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:5000'
  brokerUrl: 'http://localhost:8082'
  ...

workspaces:
  a:
    width: 45
    height: 100
    ...
  b:
    width: 56
    height: 125
    ...
```

I would like to keep the content in current `application.yaml` in multiple files in subfolders.

Let's say `connection.yaml` will contain

```
connection:
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:5000'
  brokerUrl: 'http://localhost:8082'
  ...
```

`workspace-a.yaml`
will contain

```
workspaces:
  a:
    width: 45
    height: 100
    ...
```

and lastly, `workspace-b.yaml` will contain

```
workspaces:
  a:
    width: 56
    height: 125
    ...
```

at the end the structure will be like

```
/resources
  application.yaml
  application-local.yaml
  application-test.yaml
  application-dev.yaml
  connection.yaml
  /workspaces
    a.yaml
    b.yaml
```

I've tried to put the following code in `application.yaml` but it didn't work.

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: 'local'
    include:
      - connection.yaml
      - workspaces/a.yaml
      - workspaces/b.yaml
```

I also have tried different formats like

```
- classpath:/workspaces/a.yaml
- ./workspaces/a.yaml
- file:./workspaces/a.yaml
```

Please help :'(

Comment: You can use the @PropertySource annotation for this. [Check this thread please](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23134869/spring-boot-how-to-use-multiple-yml-files)

Comment: Thank you so much but the file is very large and would be splitted into many small files, I'm not sure if @PropertySource will help in this case. I kinda want a clean and nice code. Do you have any other alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

Since Spring-Boot 2.4 you can use `spring.config.import` to import into your config.

So you could use something like this in your application.yml

`spring.config.import: connection.yml`

Spring Blog post [here](https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/config-file-processing-in-spring-boot-2-4)

Answer (score 1):

You could try naming your subconfigs like this `application-a.yaml`,`application-b.yaml` and then use it in `application.yaml`

```
spring:
   profiles:
      include:
         a,
         b,
         ...
```

The idea taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40500683/10938777

Comment: The problem is I have to keep `application-a.yaml` and `application-b.yaml` under the same folder as the `application.yaml`. I want to keep them in a sub-folder, but thank you so much :D

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't have better solution for you. You can use multiple source file this annotation: [PropertySources annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySources.html)

This annotation can bind multiple PropertySource into one configuration.

For example:

`@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource("/file1.properties"),
        @PropertySource("/file2.properties")
})`

Comment: `@PropertySources`, unfortunately, doesn't work with yaml files, but I'm trying to find the workaround here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271468/spring-propertysource-using-yaml