# In Spring Boot how to use the properties from different configuration files at the same time?

Tags: spring-boot

I have an `application.yml` file and a `sensitive-data.yml`. I would like the properties in these files to be used brushed together. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can use @PropertySource

```
@PropertySource("classpath:foo.properties")
@PropertySource("classpath:bar.properties")
public class PropertiesWithJavaConfig {
    //...
}
```

This link will help you: https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring

Comment: First of all, I have yml files, and if I'm not mistaken, PropertySource only works with properties files. Also, I would be interested if this could be done outside of code.

Comment: Maybe this approach will work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23134869/spring-boot-how-to-use-multiple-yml-files

Comment: I marked this accepted because it solved my problem, but I am still waiting for a more appropriate solution.